# Catch UIView content redraw

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I want add filter to UIView like in eBay app. I use GPUImage framework. I created a class, inherited from UIView and added UIButton and UIActivityIndicatorView to this view. And I want to catch redraw moment and apply filter for new image/texture. E.g. when I tapped on button, and button become hightliten.

```
@interface MyCALayer : CALayer
@end

@implementation MyCALayer
- (void)renderInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    [super renderInContext:ctx];
    NSLog(@"%@", @"CALayer redraw");
}
@end

@implementation MyView
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [MyCALayer class];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    NSLog(@"%@", @"UIView redraw");    
}
@end
```

UIView and CALayer redraw just 1 time. When I click to button, NSLog doesn't call. On update activity indicator log doesn't call too. How can I catch changing content in view? Is there any way to get an image/texture that is displayed on the screen from UIView without redraw this view in context?

Answer (score 0):

You can request `UIView` to redraw (call `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`) like this:

```
[view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Documentation says:

> You can use this method or the setNeedsDisplayInRect: to notify the
>   system that your view’s contents need to be redrawn.

Or you can use

```
view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

> Redisplays the view when the bounds change by invoking the setNeedsDisplay method.

Comment: I need catch change image/texture that produce UIView. When I tap to button, button change own image/texture to present. I want catch this moment. Sorry for my english, if I explained poorly.